# Yocto build opengl cts failed

Tags: opengl, yocto

I am trying to build opengl cts into yocto. I created a recipe to do so:

```
DESCRIPTION = "OpenGL CTS"
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"
PR = "r0" 
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=67d07a07ec29a50a3ded12b2ba952257"

SRCREV = "77705f0d7a813bdac9c91385e46bff98b16320c9"
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/KhronosGroup/VK-GL-CTS.git;protocol=https"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig cmake
```

The build process for the above recipe failed with the following output at do_compile() method:

```
| [ 17%] Linking CXX static library libglutil.a
| cd /home/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/deqp/1.0-r0/build/framework/opengl && /home/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
| cd /home/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/deqp/1.0-r0/build/framework/opengl && /fsl-arm-yocto-bsp/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ar qc libglutil.a  CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluContextInfo.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluDefs.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluDrawUtil.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluES3PlusWrapperContext.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluFboRenderContext.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluPixelTransfer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluProgramInterfaceQuery.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluRenderConfig.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluRenderContext.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluShaderProgram.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluShaderUtil.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluStateReset.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluTexture.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluTextureUtil.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluTextureTestUtil.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluVarType.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluVarTypeUtil.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluStrUtil.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluCallLogWrapper.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluObjectWrapper.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluContextFactory.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluDummyRenderContext.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluPlatform.cpp.o CMakeFiles/glutil.dir/gluShaderLibrary.cpp.o
| /home/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp/build-x11/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-ranlib libglutil.a
| make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/deqp/1.0-r0/build'
| [ 17%] Built target glutil
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/fsl-arm-yocto-bsp/build-x11/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/deqp/1.0-r0/build'
| Makefile:86: recipe for target 'all' failed
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
```

Comment: The real compile error probably happens earlier: At least it's not included in your snippet. Also, the recipe is unlikely to work as it is: you don't list any dependencies but the CTS is likely to have some (you might have the dependencies in your sysroot already so for now it looks like it's working). I suggest reading the cmake files and configuration output carefully and adding the correct DEPENDS. `wipe-sysroot` script can be useful as well: if you do that and cleansstate the recipe, you can then build it with just the listed dependencies.

Comment: (Note that I'm assuming you use a released Yocto: current Yocto master behaves differently with regards to sysroots. On master the sysroot only ever contains what you depend on)